# Regarding nature of strcpy() function in C

Tags: c

I'm trying the following mentioned code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buff[12];
    unsigned int length;
    while(1)
    {
    strcpy(buff,"Message123456789\n\r");
    length = strlen(buff);
    printf("%s\n",buff);
    printf("String length= %d",length);
    }
}
```

The output is:

**String length= 18Message123456789**

So, I want to ask if the buff array is only 12 character long then how it is accommodating a 18 character string in itself?

Comment: Or this? [How can the strcpy function copy a large string into a smaller string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65378690/7509065)

Comment: C have *no* bounds-checking. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*. And it's your responsibility as the programmer to make sure such things does not happen.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica  Thankyou for you help. The articles really helped with the issue.

Comment: If you put 18 people in a vehicle designed for 12, sometimes it will break, sometimes not. If you ride over a bump, it will definitely break. The 6 extra people are hanging off the back. Swerve round a corner, and they'll fall off.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "C have no bounds-checking." is more like "C does not require  bounds-checking." as an implementation _may_ have  bounds-checking.